# IF statement skipping to else when it should be true

Tags: java, android-studio

I've written an IF statement that compares two strings on a click of a button and opens an activity if they're the same.

```
buttonAcess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(insertedValue.equals(value)){

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    Toast.makeText(SecretCode.this, "Beep Boop!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else Toast.makeText(SecretCode.this, "Beep! " + editTextCode.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

The String `value` is "919620833".

When inserting that to `insertedValue` the if simply doesn't give me anything and skips to the else where, as a debug measure, I ask it to tell me what value is on the `editText` which before the IF statement outputs it's value to `insertedValue` as can be seen here:

```
final String insertedValue = editTextCode.getText().toString();
```

The value written on the editText is the same on the `value` string.

I really don't know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Is there any whitespace unknowingly getting added?  Try adding trim() editTextCode.getText().toString().trim()

Comment: Hi @SayantanMandal there shouldn't be any since I only allow the insertion of numbers, either way I've done that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Print the two Strings so you can see what is different.  Be sure to add delimiters to the print statement: println(">" + theString + "<") so you can see if there are any spaces/

Comment: You need to get the current `EditText` text inside `onClick()`. Wherever you have that last line now, `insertedValue` won't have the current text in it when you do the comparison. You don't even really need the `insertedValue` variable. You can simply do `if (editTextCode.getText().toString().equals(value)) ...`.

Comment: @NormR there are no white spaces!

Comment: @MikeM. Yes that worked, I didn't know I had to add that line to the click of the button.Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I suggested another question with the same issue as a duplicate, so that we can close out your question, and it will show as resolved. Please do select it as having solved your problem. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for that link, yes it does explain perfectly why it wouldn't work. Silly me